# Matrix multiplication java 1.8

Tags: java, matrix-multiplication, java-stream

Do you think it would be possible to implement sparse matrix operations using the new Stream interface in Java 1.8 ? If yes, how do we need to implement the matrixes and the operations. Clearly, I am looking for it for being able eventually to use the "automatic" parallelization.

Comment: Seems like it should be possible. Have you actually tried to implement it yourself?

Comment: No, I did not but I was thinking to search some analogous in scala.

Comment: Certainly an interesting question (and if I had more time, I'd give it a try), but there maybe some caveats (as far as I can judge this - I'm not an expert) : 1. There are dozens of possible sparse matrix representations - which one to use? 2. The concept of *streaming* does probably not play well together with the strict access patterns that are necessary for the multiplication and different for both input matrices, and for the result matrix. 3. The *parallel* algorithms for sparse GEMM often build on an *explicit* parallelization to a known number of processors...

Comment: ... and relying on the automatic parallelization with an "unknown" number of threads (that is used in streams) makes it impossible to exploit this information. 4. One would have to build this on *primitive* streams (`float`, `double`) to avoid (un)boxing of `Float` and `Double`. 5. The performance may largely depend on caching, which also can not be influenced with streams. - Regardless of all that, I'd really like to see some approaches here, so +1

Comment: Once you got rid of your account trouble, maybe you can add the new information in the original question by editing it. For example, if you are actually more interested in a "SparseMatrix*DenseVector" multiplication, this would be a different story.

Answer (score 2):

It can *clearly* be done. How about something like below for a simple SPMV (Sparse matrix vector multiplication), with the sparse matrix represented in the coordinate [COO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix#Coordinate_list_.28COO.29) format (the simplest sparse format out there):

```
class COO {
    int x, y, value;
}

public static ArrayList<Integer> spmv(List<COO> values, ArrayList<Integer> v) {
    final ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(Collections.nCopies(v.size(), 0));
    values.stream().forEach(
            coo -> result.set(coo.x, result.get(coo.x) + coo.value * v.get(coo.y))
    );
    return result;
}
```

But I sincerely suggest you use something pre-coded, if you don't want to spend the next 3 years of your life understanding the performance implications of sparse matrix operations.
This is quite a large research/optimisation topic and there are many factors to consider like (just off the top of my head):

1. scheduling / reordering of matrix values to improve cache performance
2. using an optimal storage format for specific problems (e.g. see this survey on [netlib](http://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node90.html))

There are many implementations out there that can achieve *orders of magnitude* improvements in performance versus hand crafted implementation. To name a few, check out:

1. [Intel MKL Sparse BLAS](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/mkl/mklman/index.htm)
2. [Nvidia's cuBLAS](https://developer.nvidia.com/cublas)

I would just write bindings to those if they don't exist already, although something like [la4j](http://la4j.org/) looks quite promising.